# Does Spring LDAP (Spring Data Repository) support repository customization?

Tags: spring-data, spring-ldap

I am using Spring LDAP 2.3.1 and want to customize my repository by adding my own create method.  I was hoping I could use the functionality described in section 2.6 of the Spring Data Commons documentation but it did not seem to work.

Is this functionality implemented for Spring LDAP?

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-ldap/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html?

Comment: Yes I've looked at LdapTemplate.  I guess to use that  I can't use the LdapRepository Interface?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with own create method. Custom repository implementations are available for every Spring Data module, see [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/ldap/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

Comment: Have you ever tried this with Spring Ldap?  I followed the example in those docs exactly and got errors that my custom create method was not found.  Maybe I did something wrong.  I just wanted to confirm whether the customization was really implemented for Spring Ldap.

Comment: Here's some sample code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-ldap/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/ldap/repository/config/CustomRepositoryBaseClassTests.java. Care to post your (minimal) code example?

Comment: Thanks very much.  I will try that and if it fails I'll post the code and error.

Comment: I have this working based on that example but I still have a question.  I created my CustomizedRepo and CustomizedRepoImpl for a specific Type.  I only want the impl to apply to that one type.  To get it to work I had to include the @EnableLdapRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true, repositoryBaseClass = CustomizedLdapRepositoryImpl.class) pointing to my impl class.  So how would I create another extended repository for a different type?  I assume I would need to indicate somehow that it would use a different repositoryBaseClass?

Comment: To clarify that comment the example from mp911de was to customize a base repo.  I want to customize a repo for one type of ldap object.  There is an example in spring-data-ldap in the same project.  The test class is CdiExtensionIntegrationTests.    If I try to run the test I get compilation errors. I don't know if I am missing something or if there is a bug.

Comment: The errors are:  Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.235 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.cdi.CdiExtensionIntegrationTests
returnOneFromCustomImpl(org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.cdi.CdiExtensionIntegrationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.004 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Error: 
Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getSampleRepository() is undefined for the type RepositoryClient

 at org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.cdi.CdiExtensionIntegrationTests.returnOneFromCustomImpl(CdiExtensionIntegrationTests.java:77)